# How can I split hyperledger fabcic peers on 2 instances?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to modify [the Getting Started example](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) of Hyperledger fabric v1.0.
The source codes are in examples/e2e_cli directory.

The original scenario is 4 peers, 1 ordering service, and 1 cli service.

What I want to achieve is 3 peers, 1 ordering service, and 1 cli service on 1 cloud instance(instance A) and 1 peer on another instance(instance B).

Since blockchain is distributed ledger, I want to test it on multiple instances.

What I did was...

1. Start 3 peers and 1 cli and 1 ordering on instance A. I commented out peer2 section of docker-compose.yaml.
2. Start 1 peer on instance B. I copied peer2 section of the docker-compose.yaml and executed docker-compose -f only-peer2.yaml up
3. Follow the instruction, the "Manually execute the transactions", to create, and instantiate a channel and try to let peers join on the channel.

Here's the code I tried on cli to let the peer on instance B to join the channel.

peer2 on instance B Join channel:

```
CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peer/peer2/localMspConfig
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=<IP address of instance B>:9051
CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org0MSP"
CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peer/peer2/localMspConfig/cacerts/peerOrg1.pem
peer channel join -b mychannel.block
```

I just changed **peer2** to **IP address of instance B**.

But I got errors and I could not let peer2 on instance B join the channel.

Here's error messages.

Instance A ( CLI ):

```
Error: Error getting endorser client channel: PEER_CONNECTIONERROR - Error trying to connect to local peer: grpc: timed out when dialing
```

Instance B ( peer2 ):

```
peer2    | 2017/04/01 22:56:32 grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "<IP address of instance A>:1177": EOF
peer2    | 2017/04/01 22:56:34 grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "<IP address of instance A>:1178": read tcp 172.19.0.2:7051->52.183.102.216:1178: read: connection reset by peer
```

Since I'm new to blockchain and Hyperledger in general, I may not understand basic of authentication mechanism. But I think having working example with 2 instances is great starting point.

Since I can go through the original scenario (which use only 1 instance) without any error, my server settings should by okay...

Please give me hints.

Thank you!

Comment: The same error happened to me when I ran the `peer channel join -b mychannel.block` command, after modifying the `examples/e2e_cli/docker-compose.yaml` according to the Using CouchDB section (un-comment all commented statements relating to CouchDB containers and peer container use of CouchDB).

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit dated, as it refers to the getting started sample for the 1.0.0-alpha release. However, there are indeed resources for setting up a network on multiple hosts.

[This one](https://github.com/litong01/fabric-deploy) leverages Ansible, OpenStack and Kubernetes and is in the process of being merged into Hyperledger Cello. [This one](https://github.com/yacovm/fabricDeployment) will deploy nodes to pre-provisioned VMs. There are likely other examples.